# Inconsistent behaviour using sqlite3.Row to index into results by name

Tags: python, sqlite, indexing

In my Python application I have been using sqlite3.Row as the row factory to index results by name for a while with no issues.  Recently I moved my application to a new server (no code changes), and I discovered this method of indexing is now unexpectedly failing on the new server given quite a specific condition.  I cannot see any explanation for it.

The problem seems to occur on the new server when I have the `DISTINCT` keyword in my select query:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('create table test ([name] text)')
c.execute("insert into test values ('testing')")
conn.commit()

c.execute('select [name] from test')
row = c.fetchone()
print row['name'] # works fine on both machines

c.execute('select distinct [name] from test') # add distinct keyword
row = c.fetchone()
print row['name'] # fails on new server (no item with that key)
```

As you can see I am able to sandbox this problem using an in-memory database, so the problem is nothing to do with my existing data.  Both machines are Debian based (old: Ubuntu 8.10, new: Debian 5.0.3) and both machines are running Python 2.5.2.  I believe the sqlite3 module is a core part of the Python install, so I do not know how this subtle breakage can be occurring since the python versions are identical.

Has anyone got any ideas, or seen anything like this before?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: It failed for me (Python 2.5.2) at first, but now I can't reproduce it with the very same code. Does it happen everytime? And what happens when you pass `detect_types = sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES` to the `connect(":memory:")` call?

Comment: Good idea.  I've just tried adding `sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES` in but that hasn't helped.  Out of interest, I have just discovered that if I change the select statement to `'select distinct [name] as name from test'`, then it works - but that's not really helping to explain the problem to me, and doesn't seem like a nice solution to have to implement.

Comment: @AndiDog also, yep this problem happens reliably every time.

Comment: Have you compared/diff'ed the files in /usr/lib/python2.5/sqlite3 on the two machines?

Comment: I have compared the Python 2.5/2.6 sqlite3 sources and the only notable difference I could find was the change from `if (self->connection->detect_types & PARSE_COLNAMES) {` to `if (self->connection->detect_types | PARSE_COLNAMES) {`. That's why I thought the detect_types parameter might help. Maybe you should ask this on the Python mailing list?! The developers know more about the internals.

Comment: @unutbu I've just run `diff -rq` against the two directories and found that all of the `.pyc` files in there are different.  I thought `.pyc` files were platform independent, so it surprises me somewhat that these differ.  All of the `.py` files match, though.  Deleting and re-creating the `.pyc` files hasn't fixed the problem

Comment: @cdlk: Maybe the /usr/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so or /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 files are different?

Comment: @unutbu Both of those files are indeed pretty different across the two machines (based upon filesize).  I am assuming that these `.so` files are being installed from the packages in the package repository - perhaps different distros are building these packages in different ways..?

Comment: @cdlk: `apt-cache show libsqlite3-0` will show the version of sqlite3 installed. It sounds like Ubuntu 8.10 and Debian 5.0.3 have packaged different versions. http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libsqlite3-0&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all shows Debian 5.0.3 uses sqlite3 version 3.5.9-6. Usually you can find similar information for Ubuntu at http://packages.ubuntu.com/, but info on 8.10 seems to have been removed...

Comment: @unutbu Yep, they're different. The Ubuntu machine has version 3.4.2-2.  The Debian has 3.5.9-6 as you say.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the line

```
print row.keys()
```

instead of "print row['name']" to see what column 0's actual name is in the second case (it's probably altered by the "DISTINCT" keyword).

Alternatively you can use row[0] in this case, but that's most likely not what you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a different, but similar, problem but googling "indexerror no item with that key" led me to this question.  In my case the issue was that different sqlite versions appear to handle row key names in row_factory = sqlite3.Row mode differently.  In sqlite 3.24.0, a query like:

```
select table.col
from table
```

...creates a key in the row dictionary like `col`.  But older versions appear to use the qualified key like `table.col`.  Providing an explicit alias or not qualifying the column is a workaround.  e.g:

```
select table.col as "col"
from table
```

Or:

```
select col
from table
```